# expected expression error (about String) in Xcode iOS 5

Tags: objective-c

```
+(NSArray *)rankStrings
{
    return @[@"?",@"A",@"2",@"3",...,@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"];           

}
```

the code has error at "..."  ,expected expression error

But I don not know where the code is wrong

I hope the one who could tell me the reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the `...` in your code with actual strings, or remove it.

For example:

```
+(NSArray *)rankStrings
{
    return @[@"?",@"A",@"2",@"3",@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"];           

}
```

By the way, did you mean "Xcode 5" instead of "Xcode iOS 5"?